# Como devolver un arreglo compuesto

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy tratando de meter en una variable todos los datos que necesito para hacer una tabla, me explico, tengo una base de datos con una tabla equipos, una tabla area, y una tabla clasificacion, necesito dado un area marcar con una X los meses en que el equipo lleva mantenimiento lo cual es determinado por su clasificacion. mi idea era meter en un arreglo cada equipo acompañado de un arreglo de 12 espacios que en las posiciones correspondientes al mes que llelva mantenimiento guardar una X.

```
public function index($id)
{
    $area=AreaResponsabilidad::find($id);
    $equipos=Equipo::all();
    $data=$this->planificar($equipos,$area);
    return view('reportes.AT3')->with('data',$data);
}
private function planificar($equipos,AreaResponsabilidad $area)
{
    foreach ($equipos as $equipo)
    {
        $con=0;
        if ($equipo->area_id==$area->id)
        {
            $resp[$con++]=['equipo'=>$equipo,'plan'=>$this->planificar_equipo($equipo)];
        }
    }
    return $resp;
}
private function planificar_equipo($equipo)
{
    $meses=Clasificacion::find($equipo->clasificacion_id)->meses;
    for ($i=1;$i<=12;$i+=$meses)
    {
        if ($i==8)
        {
            $i++;
        }
        else
        {
            $plan[$i-1]='X';
        }
    }
    return $plan;
}
```

pero em dice que cuando en la vista pongo por ejemplo `@foreach($data as $d) {{$d->plan[0]}} @endforeach`

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: La respuesta de @Shaz es correcta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás intentando acceder un array como si fuera un objeto, asumo que lo correcto sería tratarlo como un array:

```
@foreach($data as $d) {{$d['plan'][0]}} @endforeach
```

Comment: En vez de poner -1, pueden comentar porque no soluciona esto la pregunta.